# suddenly my app can't fetch data from friestore on my flutter project

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

suddenly i cant fetch data inside of the firestore database. tried to change `google-services.json` and still did't fetch data from firestore. and i tried to disconnect from my firebase project that look like this. [image]

did this already and reconnect the app, welp still didnt help at all. they keep saying

```
W/Firestore(16571): (24.1.1) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(products order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
E/flutter (16571): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
```

is there's anything that can help?. oh and i tried to change the rules too into this

```
 service cloud.firestore {   match /databases/{database}/documents {
 match /{document=**} {
   allow read: if auth != null;
   allow write: if auth != null;
  }  
 } 
}
```

this si how i use the ./gradlew signinReport
[image]

and i already update the newest SHA-1 and SHA-256 in my firebase project setting that look like that in the top one

Comment: Please check if authentication is working or not signing in from another user

Comment: auth didnt work. they say this to me. `This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. please verify that the correct package nam and SHA-1 are configured in the firebase console. [A safety_net_token was passed, but no matching SHA-256 was refistered in the firebase console.please make sure that this application's packagename/SHA256 pair is registered in the firebase console]` but i change the SHA and download the new google-services.json and put it in my android file. welp still error

Comment: @VinamraJaiswal im surely use the ./gradlew signinReport and try to check the newly image that i will provide on the question as more information that might help